# PHP not receiving post from $resource AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, ngresource

I have a factory service in Angular that is successfully posting my email in the HTTP request which I have verified with Firebug, but the email is not being seen by my PHP file. I am reaching my PHP file since I can echo a response from it, but the email value I sent it is not being received as I have already mentioned.

Controller (partial):

```
$scope.subscribe = function() {
        if($scope.email.length > 0) {
            Subscribe.save({},$scope.email);
        } else {
            alert("Please enter your email address");
        }
    }
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('Subscribe', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource( 'server/restdb.php:email', 
        {email: '@email'},
        {

        }
    ); 
}]);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo 'email: '.$_REQUEST['email'];
```

I have also tried using `$_POST` to get the email as well.

So to recap:

- Posts email in HTTP request successfully.
- PHP file is being accessed and getting response from it.
- PHP not receiving the email value I sent it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
$aRequest = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
echo 'email: ' . $aRequest['email'];
```

Comment: Thank you this works! Also this answers my question that i asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193281/how-to-use-angularjs-resource-with-php-script

Answer (score 0):

Oh, $resource.save is a bit "weird".

you should use it this way :

```
var myData = new Subscribe({email: $scope.email});
myData.save();
```

and you can simplify the factory to something like :

```
app.factory('Subscribe', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource( 'server/restdb.php', {}, {}
    ); 
}]);
```

Look a bit more at the doc : [angular.js $resources](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)