# How to use angularjs $resource with php script

Tags: php, angularjs

i have question related to PHP - AngularJs, so i have simple PHP script

```
<?php
require_once '../../dbConnect.php';

$driverId = $_POST['driverId'];

if (isset($_POST['driverId'])) {

        $sql = "delete from drivers where driver_id='$driverId'";

        if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $mysqli->error;
        }

        $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

At the moment i pass data to script like this

```
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/drivers/deleteDriver.php',
    data: $.param(driverObject),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});
```

And i don't like that code, on other Java project i send params to end points with angularjs $resource service like this

```
var deleteDriverResouce = $resource('/api/drivers/deleteDriver.php');

function deleteDriver() {
  deleteDriverResouce.save(driverObject);
}
```

And as you can see that is cleaner code and easier to use, i'm wondering can i use $resource service to pass object to php script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have found solution and i will share it here so maybe someone will need it. In order to use AngularJs $resource service you just need to make small change in PHP script, just add `$object = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);` on that way you can access to object that you sent via $resource. And here is example of one working PHP script.

```
<?php
require_once '../dbConnect.php';
session_start();

$object = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

if (isset($object['email']) && isset($object['password'])) {

    $email = $object['email'];
    $password = $object['password'];
    $query="select * from members where email='$email'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($row) {
        if (password_verify($object['password'], $row['password'])) {
            $_SESSION["id"] = $row['id'];
            echo 'Login Success!';
        } else {
            session_destroy();
            var_dump(http_response_code(400));
        }
    } else {
        session_destroy();
        var_dump(http_response_code(406));
    }

    $mysqli->close();
} else {
    session_destroy();
    var_dump(http_response_code(400));
}
?>
```

And on UI i have this simple and minimal code:

```
var userLoginObject = {
  email: 'login@email.com',
  password: 'password123'
};

var authenticationResource = $resource('/api/authentication/authenticate.php');

function logIn() {
  authenticationResource.save(userLoginObject );
}
```

That's much better and cleaner than using ugly

```
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/drivers/authenticate.php',
    data: $.param(userLoginObject),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});
```